# DO USA 3V DC 3A have a standard plug size?

Tags: power-supply

I need a replacement 12 VDC 3A power supply. Not sure of plug size. All the ones I've seen online are 5.5mm x 2.1mm

And the one I have (12 VDC but 1 A) is the right size and *looks* (ha ha!) like the 3A ones.

Answer (score 1):

> DO USA 3V DC 3A have a standard plug size?

No.  None of them do.

However, you have a existing supply that it sounds like you're going to scrap.  You can get any 12 V 3 A (or more) supply you want, and attach the DC cord from the old supply to the new one.

Beware of polarity.  There is no standard for that either.  Most likely the polarity is marked somewhere on the existing supply or on the device.

Comment: Good idea.   I suspect you're right but want to  wait a bit on Accepting. (If you have any sort of reference for your answer, I'll considering Accepting).

Comment: @Clay: You really should wait at least 24 hours before accepting any answer.  That way everyone has one waking day to answer, no matter where in the world they are.  You don't know what others might say, and many of them will skip questions with accepted answers.  I know I do that.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, what exactly do you think is wrong?